# how to return one row of an [n][3] array?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to return one,two or more rows of an [n][3] array. For example, for this array

```
{
    {1,11,5},
    {2,6,7},
    {3,13,9},
    {12,7,16},
    {14,3,25},
    {19,18,22},
    {23,13,29},
    {24,4,28}
}
```

I want to return `{1,11,5}` or `{2,6,7},{19,18,22},{24,4,28}` .How can I do this?

```
public static int[][] horizontal_view(int first, int end) {
    if (first == end)
        return * ;  //i want to return here two or more row of an [8][3] array

    int mid = (first + end) / 2;
    int[][] X = horizontal_view(first, mid);
    int[][] Y = horizontal_view(mid + 1, end);
    return merge(X, Y);
}
```

Comment: Do you aware that your method returns an `int[][]` ? You cannot return a int[].

Comment: if you want to return {2,6,7}, why not just do : array[1], it will return {2,6,7} ..

Answer (score 2):

If you won't modify the array, you can simply state:

```
int[] row = array[1];
```

In case you will modify the row, and don't want this modifications to be visible in the `array`, you can clone the array:

```
int[] rowclone = (int[]) array[1].clone();
```

Comment: Correct, maybe should make a clone, in "int" type it doesn't matter, but if it is about objects, it might cause problem later.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It however depends. Sometimes you want the raw data. For instance if you give the row to a method that should fill the row with data and you want to fill the entire `array`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you cant return an array. I would kindly advise you to store that array into a string. To get that row you must say array[1][3];

Store that info into a string value then return it

Comment: Why cannot you return an array? This luckily is Java, not C :)